# Understanding code duplication in template specializations of std::complex<T>

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, std

I was looking at the `<complex>` implementations of the C++ Standard Library. I noticed for all of the current GNU, LLVM and MSVC implementations, there is a huge amount of code duplication for template specializations for types `float` `double` and `long double`, but I don't know why.

Take the MSVC code at https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/complex as an example, consider the class template and its specializations

```cpp
template <class _Ty>
class complex;
template <>
class complex<float>;
template <>
class complex<double>;
template <>
class complex<long double>;
```

There are already definitions in the general class template. Take one definition for `operator*=` as an example,

```cpp
template <class _Ty>
class complex : public _Complex_base<_Ty, _Complex_value<_Ty>> {
public:
    // ...
    _CONSTEXPR20 complex& operator*=(const _Ty& _Right) {
        this->_Val[_RE] = this->_Val[_RE] * _Right;
        this->_Val[_IM] = this->_Val[_IM] * _Right;
        return *this;
    }
    // ...
};
```

Why is this kind of code repeated again and again for almost all member functions in the specializations for `float` `double` and `long double` as below?

```cpp
template <>
class complex<double> : public _Complex_base<double, _Dcomplex_value> {
public:
    // ...
    _CONSTEXPR20 complex& operator*=(const _Ty& _Right) {
        _Val[_RE] = _Val[_RE] * _Right;
        _Val[_IM] = _Val[_IM] * _Right;
        return *this;
    }
    // ...
};
```

What is the reason for such code duplication in the template specializations for `std::complex<T>`?

---

For reference, in the above MSVC code, it is

```cpp
using _Dcomplex_value = _CSTD _C_double_complex;
```

For reference, the GNU implementation of `<complex>` can be found at https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/complex

For reference, the LLVM implementation of `<complex>` can be found at https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/complex

For reference, the MSVC implementation of `<complex>` can be found at MSVC code at https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/complex

Comment: I assume `_Dcomplex_value` is in some way different from `_Complex_value<double>`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to open an issue at their github site and ask the actual authors?

Comment: It appears that `_C_double_complex` is shared by C library implementation of `complex.h` Perhaps the shared structure ensures that C++ `std::complex<double>` and C `double complex` are ABI-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the reason for such code duplication

Short answer: `return *this`

You need to have each operator defined in the specializations in order to be able to return the correct type. Otherwise they would return references to the base class.

You *could* call the base class operator in the derived class, like

```
    _CONSTEXPR20 complex& operator*=(const _Ty& _Right) {
       _Complex_base<_Ty, _Complex_value<_Ty>>::operator*=(_Right);
       return *this;
   }
```

but, even though is reduces repetition it really doesn't reduce the code size, or make it any more readable.

Comment: A templated version will also return the correct type. No idea what should be different...

Comment: @Klaus - Yes, but you need to have the specializations because the converting constructors are slightly different. And once you are there, you also need the operators in the derived classes.

Comment: Sorry, no :-) You can also have the common part as fully non specialized version while having other things different in specializations. Technically there is no reason to duplicate identical code. But sometimes it is much easier to simply copy paste the stuff, do some minor changes where needed and pack it into a file :-)